How to change the datatype of an array according to the input at runtime?
I'm trying to implement a matrix class in VBA. To save up memory, I would like to use 1 variable. For different use cases, I would like this variable to have a datatype according to the input. My current code would look like this:
Public Sub Initialize(ByVal Row As Integer, ByVal Column As Integer, ByVal DataType As String)

    p_Row = Row
    p_Column = Column
    Select Case DataType
        Case "Integer"
            Dim p_Array(Row, Column) As Integer
        Case "Single"
            Dim p_Array(Row, Column) As Single
        Case "Double"
        
        Case "Long"
        
        Case "LongLong"
        
        Case Else
            AL_Error_Print 7, 1, "AL_Matrix"
            AL_Error_Show 7, 1, "AL_Matrix"
    End Select

End Sub

Case Else is a custom Errorhandler and has nothing to do with the functionality of this class. I know that my approach here is not valid.
Is there any workaround to achieve 1 variable that can contain different datatypes WITHOUT the variant type?

You can use ReDim instead of Dim as below:
Public p_Array
Public Sub Initialize(ByVal Row As Integer, ByVal Column As Integer, ByVal DataType As String)

 '   p_Row = Row
 '   p_Column = Column
    Select Case DataType
        Case "Integer"
            ReDim p_Array(Row, Column) As Integer
        Case "Single"
            ReDim p_Array(Row, Column) As Single
        Case "Double"
        
        Case "Long"
        
        Case "LongLong"
        
        Case Else
  '          AL_Error_Print 7, 1, "AL_Matrix"
  '          AL_Error_Show 7, 1, "AL_Matrix"
    End Select

End Sub
Sub Test()
   Initialize 4, 3, "Integer"
   p_Array(1, 1) = 3.56
   Debug.Print p_Array(1, 1)   ' 4
   Initialize 2, 2, "Single"
   p_Array(2, 2) = Log(2)
   Debug.Print p_Array(2, 2)   ' 0.6931472
End Sub


I tried that but VBA threw an error, that Array´s cant be assigned to a different datatype. Either way thanks for your help. I changed my solution to using the Variant datatype.

Public p_Array is declared without predefined data type. I have tested the code.

It worked today. Dont know what i did wrong last time but your solutions works. Thank you.

My own solution is to use the variant datatype or implement for each type all functions, like i did with stuff like sorting algorithms.
